# problems with messages queue

Tags: c, multithreading

this program should create a fixed number of childs (30), and these threads should communicate each other for purposes that maybe I can explain after. occurs the error 22: invalid arguments both on msgsnd and msgrcv lines.
sorry this is the first time I try to use the messages queues in C

for now I want that the father first send to child a message about a preference number, every child should receive it and write in the array called 
vettorestudenti this info. before starting do other things I have to fix this

there is a test code at the beginning in the define area:

```c
there are some structs:
 struct dati{
        pid_t sender;
        int preferenza;// the father writes a preference number in a queue that should be read by children threads
    };
    struct msgbuf {
            long mtype; //pid destinatario 
            struct dati msglist;

        };
 struct tipostudente { //array that contains info about child process

    int matricola; // ID
    int voto_AdE; //student mark
    int numeroinviti; //number of invitations
    int preferenzaGruppo; // preference
    };
    pid_t *studenti;
//FOLLOW UPDATED CODE
 struct msgbuf coda[POP_SIZE];
    int queue_id = msgget(MY_KEY, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL| 0666);
    if(queue_id==-1)
    { perror("error msgget"); }

many rows after
 /* vector of kids PIDs */
    studenti = malloc(POP_SIZE*sizeof(*studenti));
for(int u=0; u<POP_SIZE; u++)
        {
            coda[u].mtype=studenti[u];// qui il pid del destinatario
            coda[u].msglist.preferenza= funzionesceltaGrp();
            printf("funzpref22 %d  and studenti[u]= %lu \n",coda[u].msglist.preferenza, coda[u].mtype);
            if (msgsnd(queue_id, &coda[u], sizeof(coda[u])-sizeof(long), 0) == -1) 
            {

                perror("error msgsnd"); //INVALID ARGUMENT ERROR HERE

            }

        }


    for (i=0; i<POP_SIZE; i++) {//POP_SIZE volte esegue la fork
        switch (studenti[i] = fork()) {
        case -1:
            /* Handle error */
            fprintf(stderr, "%s, %d: Errore (%d) nella fork\n",
                __FILE__, __LINE__, errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0: 
            srand(getpid());
            vettorestudenti[i].matricola=rand()%999999; 

            if (msgrcv(queue_id, &coda[i], sizeof(coda[i])-sizeof(long),0, 0) == -1) 
            {

                perror("error msgrcv"); //INVALID ARGUMENT ERROR HERE
            }
            printf("messaggio ricevuto, sono lo studente %d \n",vettorestudenti[i].matricola);




            free(studenti); 
            exit(0); 

            break; //FINE CODICE STUDENTE
        default:
            //codice del padre 


            break;  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are misusing `errno`.  You are assuming if it has a non-zero value it indicates an error, which is not true.  `errno` merely indicates what the error was after an actual error condition was returned from a library function.  In the absence of positive error indication **by other means**, the value of `errno` itself is meaningless.

See [**7.5 Errors** , paragraph 4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3) of the C standard:

> The value of errno in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of errno in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is **never set to zero by any library function**. The value of errno **may be set to nonzero** by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.

For example:

```
int queue_id = msgget(MY_KEY, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL| 0666);
TEST_ERROR;
```

That code *assumes* a non-zero value for `errno` indicates an error.  It does not.  Per [the POSIX `msgget()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgget.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, `msgget()` shall return a non-negative integer, namely a message queue identifier. Otherwise, it shall return `-1` and set `errno` to indicate the error.

`errno`'s only use after `msgget()` is to indicate what error happened **if and only if** `msgget()` has already returned `-1`.

Comment: A helpful function to make use of `errno` is `perror`: `if(some_function() == -1) perror("error code is");`

Comment: so there are actually no problem with the initial purpose to send messages to children? I noticed, at first execution the return value of msgset is 0, in the next attempts is -1, the TEST_ERROR function return error 17: file exists...

Comment: now I use perror but I STILL DON'T KNOW what to do to prevent the error to occur. I updated the code at the beginning of this web page

Comment: @J.G. In general, you have to check the return value from the functions you call.  **IF** that function indicates an error (read the function's documentation to find out how it indicates an error), only then is the value in `errno` relevant - read the functions documentation to see what that `errno` value really means for that function.